allowing cors for custom header / all origin for a single custom api
I have a custom api which is set up to receive customer info from anyone, only able to be read or deleted by people who have a certain header which i had set and would have only been useable by admin on the site, so unless a hacker randomly guessed the header or hacked the route between the servers it was secure enough for basic validation.
The plugin setup is as follows. The problem was that cors won't allow my custom headers on wordpress and i'll show what i tried doing to change it.
<?php





register scripts/enqueue...

//custom json data table

function custom_post_types() {
  register_post_type('custom_data', array(
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-data'), 
      'has_archive' => true,
      'public' => true,
      'show_in_rest' => true,
      'labels' => array(
          'name' => 'Custom Data',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Data',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Data',
          'all_items' => 'All Data',
          'singular_name' => 'Data',
          'add_new' => 'Add New Data'
      ),
      'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-database'
  ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'register_custom_routes');


function register_custom_routes() {
  register_rest_route('submit/v1', 'data', array(
      array(
          'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
          'callback' => 'handle_custom_route',
          'permission_callback' => 'check_permission',
      ),
      array(
          'methods' => WP_REST_Server::CREATABLE,
          'callback' => 'handle_post_request',
          'permission_callback' => 'check_permission_2',
      ),
      array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::DELETABLE, 
        'callback' => 'handle_delete_request',
        'permission_callback' => 'check_permission',

    ),
  ));
}

function check_permission($request) {
  $header_value = $request->get_header('X-delete');
  if ($header_value !== 'password') {
    return new WP_Error('rest_forbidden', __('Unauthorized access.'), array('status' => 403));
}

return true;
}

function check_permission_2($request) {
  $header_value = $request->get_header('X-read');
  if ($header_value !== 'password') {
    return new WP_Error('rest_forbidden', __('Unauthorized access.'), array('status' => 403));
}
return true;
}

function handle_custom_route($data) {
  ...

Tried configuring the cors to allow my headers in the plugin for just this api so their overall security wouldn't be affected just this one json datatable which is sanitized and esc on read.
public function __construct() {
        add_action('init', array($this, 'onInit'));
        add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', array($this, 'add_cors_headers'), 10, 4);

...


public function add_cors_headers($served, $result, $request, $rest_server) {
   
        if ($request->get_route() === '/submit/v1/data') {
            $served = rest_ensure_response($served);
            $served->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); domain if possible
            $served->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE');
            $served->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
            $served->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, 'X-delete', 'X-read');
        }
        return $served;
    }
}



Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true is an invalid combination. You also have syntax errors on the Access-Control-Allow-Headers line
